# Automate the Endurance Testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to automate the endurance testing using `jmeter`. I have a test plan consisting of 2 thread groups, in turn having multiple requests.

I want to run the test plan first for 10 users, then for 50, then for 100...so on with each run having a pause of 20 minutes, in an automatic manner so that i do not have to sit and wait for 20 minutes and then type 50 users in the command line argument and again wait for 20 minutes and then type 100 users in the command line argument and again wait for 20 minutes and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I can have an excel file which has a column containing the thread count like: 10,20,30 etc. Then in a java program using eclipse/intellij, I can read the above values from the excel file in a loop and assign the values to a String variable: "value" inside the loop. Then inside the loop,I can invoke the jmx file as below:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\jmeter.bat -t \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\test.jmx\" -Jusers="+value+" -n -l \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\nonGUI.csv\" -j \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\jmeterLogs.log\"");Thread.sleep(120000);
```

Hope this helps others who want to perform Endurance testing using jmeter+java

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is possible using [Ultimate threadgroup](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/),

Sample should be like,
I have added steps for 10, 50, 100 users for 20 min. If needed more runs you can add more rows with customized settings.

[image]